# How do i store crawled images inside a directory?

Tags: php, html, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

After a name is submitted from a form, the php code checks whether the directory exists or not, and if the directory exists,  the images are displayed from that directory. But if the directory doesn't exist, a new directory is made. Here is the problem- the code works perfectly fine when crawling but it doesn't store the images inside the specified directory. The problem seems to be on the `file_put_contents($directory , $image);` part. Below is the full code:

```
<?php

$images = array();
$directory = 'images '.$_POST["name"];
if (file_exists($directory)) {

if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

elseif (preg_match("/\.gif$/", $file)) $images[] = $file;

}

shuffle($images);

closedir($handle);

}

?>

<div class="cycle-slideshow" >

<?php

for($i= 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

  foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
        if ($item->isFile()) {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;   
            echo '<img src="' . $path . '" class="displayed" style="max-width:100%; max-height:460px; position: absolute;
  right: 0px;   top: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;   vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; "

   />';  
        }
    }  

}

  }
else {

    include "simple_html_dom.php";
   $html = file_get_html( "https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=barrack%20obama&FORM=HDRSC2" );
    $images = $html->find('img');
    $image_count = 50; //Enter the amount of images to be shown
    $i = 0;
    foreach($images as $image){
        if($i == $image_count) break;
        $i++;

      mkdir($directory);
      file_put_contents($directory , $image);

    }
        }

?>
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the directory has write permission on it or not and if you are creating new directory than that should be created with write permission this way it will store you files and help to retrieve it from directory.

As you are already using mkdir() than try to set permission with it like

```
mkdir("dirname", 0777);
```

Comment: i tried mkdir `($directory, 0777);` but it doesn't seem to work. the error is as following:                                                                                                    
`Warning: file_put_contents(images donald trump): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\venus\photopage.php on line 1103

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in C:\xampp\htdocs\venus\photopage.php on line 1102

Warning: file_put_contents(images donald trump): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\venus\photopage.php on line 1103

 `

Comment: Can you tell where are are creating a new directory dynamically? 
Let suppose if you are creating a sub directory than it's parent directory should have 777 permission to your local system or you can also set a user group "www-data" to the parent directory, so that it will allow to create other directory inside it.

Comment: And also try to remove the 0 from 0777 from mkdir() method and check.

Comment: Removing 0 from 0777 didn't work. Actually the problem isn't creating the directory, the directory is getting created but the scraped images aren't being stored in that newly created directory.